# stack trace with multiple caller methods

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, crash, callstack

I get this kind of stack trace when my app crashes in the field, and I just can't get my head around the actual meaning of it:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object com.myapp.model.DatabaseObject.a(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.myapp.video.VideoController.hideControlsAfterDelay$1349ef(VideoController.java)
                                         setVideoView(VideoController.java)
                                         playClip(VideoController.java)
                                         playClipAtIndex(VideoController.java)
                                         playUrl(VideoController.java)
                                         updateDownloadButton(VideoController.java)
                                         stringForTimeOffset(VideoController.java)
                                         handleScrubMove(VideoController.java)
                                         animateShowHide(VideoController.java)
    at com.myapp.video.VideoPlayerActivity$2.onLoad(VideoPlayerActivity.java)
    at com.myapp.model.Moment$1.onLoad(Moment.java)
                                  onUpdate(Moment.java)
                                  onNeedsUpdate$2cf7ba29(Moment.java)
    at com.myapp.model.Moment.notifyListeners(Moment.java)
    at com.myapp.model.Moment.getKey(Moment.java)
                                setValueForKey(Moment.java)
                                valueForKeyPath(Moment.java)
                                write(Moment.java)
                                addClick(Moment.java)
    at com.myapp.model.Moment$3.onLoad(Moment.java)
    at com.myapp.model.FireDatabaseObject$1.onDataChange(FireDatabaseObject.java)
    at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(zzp.java)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(zzegf.java)
                                             zzc(zzegf.java)
                                             zzbvp(zzegf.java)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(zzeia.java)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(zzeig.java)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Why do I get a list of possible (?) callers at the point of exception?
Who tried to call com.myapp.model.DatabaseObject.a() on a null object?

Was it hideControlsAfterDelay$1349ef(), setVideoView(), playClip(), or any of the others listed?

Because hideControlsAfterDelay$1349ef() does not call com.myapp.model.DatabaseObject.a at all:

```
void hideControlsAfterDelay(long delay) {
    cancelHideControls();
    mHideControlsTimer = new Timer();
    mHideControlsTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (getActivity() != null) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        animateShowHide(false);
                        mHideControlsTimer = null;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

Same for any of theses methods really, so what's going on here?

Please note, I am not asking about the null pointer exception, I can deal with my coding mistakes, I'm asking about the shape of the stack trace: why are there several methods listed at the same level of the stack trace?

Thanks for shining a light on this.

Comment: `... what's going on here?` You are using an object without referencing it first. That's what a NullPointerException (NPE, for friends) is.

Comment: You should be a debug version of your app so that you get line numbers in your stack trace.  Maybe get more info from that.  From what you've posted so far I cannot connect the stack trace to the code either.

Comment: @Kling Klang please read the question again carefully, I know what a NPE is.

Comment: @JJF, I wish I could reproduce while running in the debugger, but I can't find the sequence of operations to get the crash. These are coming from the release version of the app in the field, which, by definition, cannot contain debug information.

Comment: If you knew what a NPE is, you would not ask this question. Since all NPEs are the same story. And they are all fixed the same way: find the unreferenced object (which is NULL, therefore the "Null" in "NullPointerException", but POINTED/referenced somewhere in your app) and reference it BEFORE using it.

Comment: @KlingKlang I think the question is about the difficulty the poster is having finding the code that's using the uninitialized value.  It's not obvious to me either how hideControlsAfterDelay causes a call to com.myapp.model.DatabaseObject.a() .

Comment: @JJF Nonetheless, it seems to be only a debug-related question, to me.

Comment: I guess stack trace aside that the database object is null and thus can't invoke the method .a().

Comment: LOL @KlingKlang, really, I know what a NPE is and, absolutely, the database object is null otherwise I wouldn't get the error. JJF got it right, I'm asking about the stack trace, not the error, I'll deal with the error when I find where it happens. My question is: is it happening in the code of hideControlsAfterDelay(), or the code of setVideoView(), or the code of playClip(), etc? Because all of these methods are listed in the stack trace as possible callers of the a() method on a null object. Yet, as you see in the code of hideControlsAfterDelay(), I do not call the a() method on any object.

Comment: I found this for deobfuscating stack traces https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/retrace

Comment: The stack trace is already deobfuscated, but your link has been really helpful @JJF, because I found this bit in the documentation of retrace that explains the multi-method mystery: "If the line numbers have been removed, mapping obfuscated method names back to their original names has become ambiguous. ReTrace will list all possible original method names for each line in the stack trace. The user can then try to deduce the actual stack trace manually, based on the logic of the program.". Many thanks! If you write this in answer I will accept it so you can get the credits for it.

Comment: I did not know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the method names have been obfuscated it is showing you all the possible original method names for each line in the stack trace.